# rails config gem issue with template rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using rails config gem to set feature flags.

Settings.yml

```
enable_grading: <%= 'true' == ENV['ENABLE_GRADING'] %>
```

When I try to hide/show some part of the template based on the feature flag, it responds inconsistently.

```
<% if Settings.enable_grading %>
   <div class='grade_tabs'>
      ...
   </div> 
<% end %>
```

So here, even if `Settings.enable_grading` is true, the `div` block is not being rendered. But if I modify this to:

```
<% if Settings.enable_grading == true %>
  <div class='grade_tabs'>
      ...
   </div>
<% end %>
```

now this starts working!(the content is rendered). This is working if we use some sort of ruby interpolation just before the condition check.

```
<%= Settings.enable_grading %>
<% if Settings.enable_grading %>
   <div class='grade_tabs'>
      ...
   </div> 
<% end %>
```

This is really weird. What is wrong in this code? I was using this gem to set feature flags before also which was working well.

Comment: What do you get if you just print `Settings.enable_grading`? In ruby everything is true except `false` and `nil`. So there's a chance this isn't getting set all. Try to restart your server if it isn't.

Comment: Hey, I know these concepts. I'm getting true itself. As I mentioned, if I put a print just before this condition, everything starts working. I don't know if that happens because of some delayed execution

Comment: Also, I have restarted my machine itself in order to debug this.